# Pushing a String to Stack<E>

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am writing a program that converts infix to postfix using a stack and LinkedList. I need to push a "(" into the stack, but the method `push()` accepts `E` item. To my knowledge, there really isn't a way to convert a `String` such as `"("` to type `E`, so I can push it. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when attempting to push the string. If someone could be as kind to review my code and maybe give me a hint in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!!

```
Stack myStack = new Stack();

list.push("(");


public void push(E item)
    {
        //private LinkedList<E> list;(This is initiated in another class.)
        list.insertAtFront(item);

    }

public void insertAtFront(E insertItem)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode< E >(insertItem);
            numElements++;
        }
        else
        {
            firstNode = new ListNode< E >(insertItem, firstNode);
            numElements++;
        }
    }
```

LinkedList.java:

```
public class LinkedList< E >
{
    private ListNode< E > firstNode;
    private ListNode< E > lastNode;
    private int numElements;
    private String name;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode = null;
        numElements = 0;
    }

    public LinkedList(String listName) 
    {
        name = listName;
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode = null;
        numElements = 0;
    }

    // Method Name      : insertAtFront
    // Parameters       : E insertItem
    // Return value(s)  : Void.
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Inserts a new element at the front of a list
    public void insertAtFront(E insertItem)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode< E >(insertItem);
            numElements++;
        }
        else
        {
            firstNode = new ListNode< E >(insertItem, firstNode);
            numElements++;
        }
    }

    // Method Name      : insertAtBack
    // Parameters       : E insertItem
    // Return value(s)  : Void.
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Inserts a new element at the back of a list
    public void insertAtBack(E insertItem)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode< E >(insertItem);
            numElements++;
        }
        else
        {
            lastNode = lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode< E >(insertItem);
            numElements++;
        }
    }

    // Method Name      : removeFromFront
    // Parameters       : 
    // Return value(s)  : 
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : 
    public E removeFromFront() throws EmptyListException
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }

        E removedItem = firstNode.data;

        if(firstNode == lastNode)
        {
            firstNode = lastNode = null;
            numElements--;
        }
        else
        {
            firstNode = firstNode.nextNode;
            numElements--;
        }

        return removedItem;
    }

    // Method Name      : removeFromBack
    // Parameters       : None.
    // Return value(s)  : E removedItem
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Removes and Returns the last element.
    public E removeFromBack() throws EmptyListException
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }

        E removedItem = lastNode.data;

        if(firstNode==lastNode)
        {
            firstNode = lastNode = null;
            numElements--;
        }
        else
        {
            ListNode< E > current = firstNode;

            while(current.nextNode != lastNode)
            {
                current = current.nextNode;
            }

            lastNode = current;
            current.nextNode = null;
            numElements--;
        }

        return removedItem;
    }

    // Method Name      : remove
    // Parameters       : int index
    // Return value(s)  : Void.
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Removes the element at the specified index.
    public void remove(int index) throws EmptyListException, IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }

        if(index<0 || index>numElements)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(name);
        }

        ListNode<E> current = firstNode;

        for(int i = 0;i<index;i++)
        {
            current = current.nextNode;
        }
        while(current.nextNode != lastNode)
        {
            current.data = current.nextNode.data;
            current = current.nextNode;
        }
        lastNode = null;
        numElements--;
    }

    // Method Name      : get
    // Parameters       : int index
    // Return value(s)  : E current.data
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Returns the value of the element at the specified index.
    public E get(int index) throws EmptyListException, IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }

        if(index<0 || index>numElements)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(name);
        }

        ListNode<E> current = firstNode;

        for(int i = 0;i<index;i++)
        {
            current = current.nextNode;
        }

        return current.data;
    }

    // Method Name      : findAndRemove
    // Parameters       : E item
    // Return value(s)  : boolean
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Searches for the specified element. Returns true it removed, false if not.
    public boolean findAndRemove(E item) throws EmptyListException
    {


        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }

        ListNode< E > current = firstNode;

        while(current.nextNode != lastNode)
        {
            if(current.data != item)
            {
                current = current.nextNode;
            }
            if(current.data == item)
            {
                while(current.nextNode != lastNode)
                {
                    current.data = current.nextNode.data;
                    current = current.nextNode;
                }
                current.data = current.nextNode.data;
                current.nextNode.data = null;
                lastNode = null;
                numElements--;
                return true;
            }

            if(current.data == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Method Name      : findItem
    // Parameters       : E item
    // Return value(s)  : int index
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Returns the index where the specified element it located.
    public int findItem(E item)
    {
        int index = 0;
        ListNode< E > current = firstNode;

        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }

        while(current.nextNode != lastNode)
        {
            if(current.data == item)
            {
                return index;
            }
            /*else if(current.data == null)
            {
                current = current.nextNode;
            }*/
            else
            {
                current = current.nextNode;
                index++;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    // Method Name      : lengthIs
    // Parameters       : None.
    // Return value(s)  : int numElements
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Returns the number of elements in the list
    public int lengthIs()
    {
        return numElements;
    }

    // Method Name      : clear
    // Parameters       : None.
    // Return value(s)  : Void.
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Clears all elements from the list
    public void clear()
    {
        numElements = 0;
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode = null;
    }

    // Method Name      : print
    // Parameters       : None.
    // Return value(s)  : Void.
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Prints each element of the list.
    public void print()
    {
        ListNode< E > current = firstNode;

        if(firstNode == null && lastNode == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Empty Integer List");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.print("The list " + name + " is: ");
            while(current.nextNode != lastNode)
            {
                if(current.data != null)
                {
                    System.out.print(current.data + " ");
                    current = current.nextNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.nextNode;

                }


            }

            if(current.data != null)
            {
                System.out.print(current.data + " ");
                current = current.nextNode;
                if(current.data != null)
                {
                    System.out.print(current.data + " ");
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }

    // Method Name      : isEmpty
    // Parameters       : None.
    // Return value(s)  : boolean
    // Partners         : None.
    // Description      : Returns true if the list is empty, false if not.
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(numElements==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Postfix.java: 
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
    public class Postfix extends Stack<Object>
{
    final static int PRECEDENCE_PLUS=  1;
    final static int PRECEDENCE_MINUS=  1;
    final static int PRECEDENCE_MULTIPLIY=  2;
    final static int PRECEDENCE_DIVIDE=  2;
    final static int PRECEDENCE_EXPONENT=  3;
    final static int PRECEDENCE_PARANTHESIS=  4;

    //Push left parenthesis '(' onto the stack
        //Append a right parenthsis ')' to the end of infix
        //While the stack is not empty, read infix from left to right and do the following:
            //If the current character in ifx is a digit, append it to postfix
            //If the current character infix is a left parenthesis, push it onto the stack
            //If the current character in infix is an operator:
                //Pop operators (if there are any) at the top of the stack while they have equals or higher precedence than the current operator, and append the popped operators to postfix.
                //Push the current character in infix onto the stack.
            //If the current character in infix is a right parenthesis:
                //Pop operators from the top of the stack and append them to postfix until a left parenthesis is at the top of the stack.
                //Pop and discard the left parenthsis from the stack

    public static boolean isOperator(char op)
    {
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+': return true;
            case '-': return true;
            case '*': return true;
            case '/': return true;
            case '%': return true;
            default: return false;
        }
    }

    public static StringBuffer infixToPostfix(StringBuffer infix) throws InvalidCharacterException
    {
        StringBuffer postfix = new StringBuffer("");

        infix.append(')');
        Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<String>();
        myStack.push("(");
        int i = 0;
        while(infix.length()>0)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(infix.charAt(i)))
            {
                postfix.append(infix.charAt(i));
                infix.delete(i,i+1);
            }
            if(infix.charAt(i) == '(')
            {
                myStack.push("(");
            }
            if(isOperator(infix.charAt(i)) == true)
            {
                Object E = myStack.peek();
                char peekedItem = E.toString().charAt(0);
                if(isOperator(peekedItem) == true)
                {
                    myStack.pop();
                    infix.delete(i,i+1);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }


        return postfix;
    }

    public static double evaluatePost(StringBuffer postfix)
    {
        return 0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidCharacterException, NullPointerException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        StringBuffer infix;

        System.out.print("Enter infix expression: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        infix = new StringBuffer(input);
        try
        {
        System.out.print("Postfix: " + infixToPostfix(infix));
        }
        catch (InvalidCharacterException E)
        {
            System.out.println(E);
        }
    }
}
```

Stack.java

```
public class Stack<E>
{
    private LinkedList<E> list;
    private String name;
    int Elements = 0;

    public Stack()
    {

    }

    public Stack(String n)
    {
        name = n;
        Elements = 0;
    }

    public void push(E item)
    {
        Elements++;
        list.insertAtFront(item);
    }

    public E pop() throws EmptyListException
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new EmptyListException(name);
        }
        Elements--;
        return list.removeFromFront();
    }

    public int lengthIs()
    {
        return Elements;
    }

    public E peek()
    {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    public void print()
    {
        list.print();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 issues: you should really read about generics in Java, and Stack's constructor should initialize the LinkedList variable.

Comment: I suggest moving this question to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mena posting non-working code on code review results in clutter that gets put on-hold as off-topic. See [CR's Help Center / on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Stack` class, you declared an instance variable `list`, but you never initialized it, so Java initialized it to `null`.

Initialize it:

```
private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
```

Comment: Wow, and this whole time I have been bashing my head over something silly. That did the trick.... Thank you!